# How does Storm KafkaSpout know all bolts are executed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

Example my topology code like this:

```
builder.setSpout("spout", new KafkaSpout);
builder.setBolt("bolt1", new Bolt1).shuffleGrouping("spout");
builder.setBolt("bolt2", new Bolt2).shuffleGrouping("bolt1");
builder.setBolt("bolt3", new Bolt3).shuffleGrouping("bolt2");
```

When bolt1 emitted, the message will be auto acked. But when bolt2 or bolt3 has exception occured, this message can't be resend, How can I retrieve failed message?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm has the concept of `tuple trees` at the helm of it. Let me try to explain using your example provided in the question.

When your `spout` calls the `collector.emit` method, the newly emitted tuple, let's call it `tuple1`, is added to `tuple tree`. This tuple reaches `bolt1` as it has subscribed to it and will receive data emitted from the `spout`. Once it receives `tuple1` as input in the `execute` method, after processing the input a new value is emitted as `tuple2` which is added in the tuple tree after `tuple1`. Before exiting the `execute` method the tuple is acknowledged by calling `collector.ack` implicitly which tells storm that `tuple1` has been processed please remove it from the tuple tree and now remains `tuple2` which is passed on to `bolt2` for processing.

Now the question arises what happens if `bolt1` is unable to acknowledge due to some reason. Storm will see that after a certain period of time, which is the topology timeout time (defaults to 30s), the tuple tree hasn't exhausted thus it will replay the tuple from the start and the same above process will follow.

Hope i am able to explain what happens on failure. For more detail please read [this](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.2/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html) or watch [this](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/cloud-applications-part2/3-2-1-anchoring-and-spout-replay-vxQoF)